# When should I answer NS queries in the ANSWER vs AUTHORITY section?

Tags: dns

Context: I'm writing an authoritative DNS name server.

When I receive an `NS` query, should I answer in the `ANSWER` section or the `AUTHORITY` section?

This is the behavior I have observed:

- queries to a recursive server always answer in `ANSWER`
- queries to an authoritative server for a zone that server serves, answer in `ANSWER`

  - ex: I query `ns1.example.com` for `example.com`
- queries to an authoritative server for a zone delegated to another server, answer in `AUTHORITY`

  - ex: I query `ns1.example.com` for `delegated.example.com`

Setting aside the behavior of recursive resolvers, it seems like the rule is "If you are not authoritative for the zone in the query (i.e., you have delegated it to another server), never put anything in the `ANSWER` section".

Do I have this correct?

Comment: "Context: I'm writing an authoritative DNS name server." Why? To learn? Or to provide really new features that do not exist yet in bind, nsd, powerDNS, knotDNS and Yadifa? Otherwise writing a proper DNS server is not easy and based on your question I fear you have many many more RFCs to read. Also as it stands your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: Please have a look at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1034#section-4.3.2 which tells exactly how an authoritative server should handle queries and what resolution algorithm to use. Make sure to read the rest about wildcards, etc. Plus of course there were later changes, like for DNSSEC, etc.

Comment: you may want to look also at https://powerdns.org/hello-dns/auth.md.html for a gentle introduction

Comment: @PatrickMevzek AFAIK, to provide new features. It's very-approximately a load balancer for the real authoritative name servers which sit behind a firewall, but I want to be able to conditionally call `setsockopt` on the connections to the backed. I'm aware I'm in a security minefield. The RFC link (specifically step 3b) was exactly what I needed. If you put that in an answer I would accept it. To your point of being off-topic, I would argue that "how to implement a DNS server" is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".